# Possible reasons for not being able to see a control from the codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

I am looking at a Main.Master with a single `<asp:Content>` control and inside that some ASP.NET login stuff (LoginView, LoginName, etc).

I tried adding a `Label` like so:

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="Welcome {0} <br />" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
```

but it doesn't show in the codebehind.

Any obvious reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Visual Studio Designer gets out of sync and does not generate the Designer code files correctly. These are some methods I've found helpful:

- Switch between HTML view and Design view.
- Make sure the project is compiled.
- Try to remove and reinsert the new control.
- Open and close the aspx file.

I haven't really found a pattern yet on when exactly Visual Studio fails to add new controls correctly to the `.designer.cs/vb` file, but a random combination of the stuff metioned above usually helped.

Comment: Besides what Heinzi has mentioned, the designer file may not be generated if there is some error in your project. Check if your project complies successfully or not - fixes errors if any and then only start making changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a line like this in your Main.master.designer.cs file (assuming you use C#)

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label1;
```

if not - add it.

Answer (score 0):

If your label is inside a LoginView then as a LoginView is a container you need to do LoginView1.FindControl("Label1") and then cast it a Label.

VB:

```
Dim label1 as Label = CType(LoginView1.FindControl("Label1"),Label)
```

C#:

```
Label label1 = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("Label1")
```